# How do I find out which service principal an azure kubernetes cluster uses?

Tags: azure-aks, service-principal

We have created an AKS (Azure Kubernetes) cluster. How can I find out which service principal is assigned to the cluster?

It seems to be not shown anywhere in the GUI.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted / not okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest way is opening up cloud shell and doing this:

```
az aks list
```

and looking at the result. it would show the id or the service principal

an alternative would be doing this:

```
az aks show -n aks_name -g rg_name --query servicePrincipalProfile
```

Comment: Ah, great, thanks; Is it this one?
`"servicePrincipalProfile": {
      "clientId": "4d33e156-0434-4505-b2c1-64a727aa7251"
    },`
... This here is a bit confusing: `"identity": {
      "principalId": null,
      "tenantId": null,
      "type": "None"
    },`

Comment: yeah, that is the cliendId

Comment: Awesome; thanks! The alternative query does not work for me; it returns an empty result. I then played around, and `az aks show -n cut-aks -g cut --query servicePrincipalProfile` works. The result is then the same as in my comment above.

Comment: ah right, since it wouldn't return an array, forgot about that. feel free to upvote\accept